# What do you call this side to side selector?

Tags: terminology

Code pen: https://codepen.io/kiwideejay/full/LzgBGQ/

It's essentially a radio button group - user must have one selected, and only one selected.

The context it's used for isn't really filling in forms - but selected different modes within an app.

As an aside - what's the best way to search these questions? I don't know what words to use.

Comment: Can u briefly explain the purpose of different modes?

Comment: Well the specific purpose I have for it is this: http://geo-art.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ (resize it to mobile). 

I'd put one of these side to side selectors in, and it changes the list of parameters and the algorithm that is playing.

Comment: You didn't ask for feedback, but I suggest making the title/label a dropdown menu or similar. This can save a few clicks when going from one 'slide' to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be simply considered a carousel with buttons instead of images or text.

I find the best way to look for the names of these elements, is to simply google a short description of it. If you are unaware of the name of the most common types of elements you can read the material design or apple guidelines. They list most kinds of elements with a short description.

Comment: Hey. The example I gave wasn't Meant to be demonstrating the range sliders, but the context where the carousel would be used